# Returning type based on non-compile time variables

Tags: c#, xna

I'll start off by saying that I don't know if this is the most optimal method of loading resources, but right now my resource manager has content submitted to it at LoadContent, then flushes its resources and stores them in a list. Then At any point in the game's code I can call query resource and it returns a type I designed as ResourceBufferElement which at any given time contains all possible types of content for xna, but only one of them isn't null.

So

```
//All of this is valid but only .Texture returns a non-null value
    QueryResource("texture").Texture
    QueryResource("texture").Model
    QueryResource("texture").SpriteFont
```

So what I'm wondering is if there was a way for me to just call QueryResource("") and it implicitly return the value it represents.

So I want to say

```
//At LoadContent
    SubmitResource("texture", typeof(Texture2D))
    SubmitResource("model", typeof(Model))
//Then at calling I want to say
  Texture2D tex = QueryResource("texture")
    or
  Model mod = QueryResource("model")
//Instead of saying this
  Texture2D tex = QueryResource("texture").Texture
    or
  Model mod = QueryResource("model").Model
```

Note: I'm already storing the type so at submit I'm saying

```
    SubmitResource("", typeof(Texture2D))
  and ResourceBufferElement keeps the Type for later use
```

Comment: You can return a *dynamic*

Comment: Why don't you just have three methods, `QueryTexture`, `QueryModel`, and `QuerySpriteFont`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
public T QueryResource<T>(string resourceName)
{
    if (T is Texture)
        return (T)QueryResource(resourceName).Texture;
    else if (T is Model)
        return (T)QueryResource(resourceName).Model;
    else if (T is SpriteFont)
        return (T)QueryResource(resourceName).SpriteFont;

    return default(T);
}
```

Which would then work as you want:

```
Texture text = QueryResource<Texture>("Resource");
```

Comment: Your method worked fine, the only thing I had to chage was to convert the return to an object then to a T. Had to do return (T)(object)actualResource

Comment: Its because you have boxed values stored in your resource manager. You need to explicitly cast to an object first, then T.